# How to display the "content" of an ObjectController?

Tags: ember.js

My ObjectController:

```
App.TestController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  content: null

App.testController = App.TestController.create()
App.testController.set("content", Ember.Object.create({ question: "Question?" }))

console.log App.testController.get("question")
```

My view:

```
{{#view App.QuizView controller="App.testController"}}
   <div>"{{question}}"</div>
{{/view}}
```

On my console, I get:

```
Question?
```

But my view is empty:

```
""
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from your template, you're not binding the controller to the view.
Replace

```
{{#view App.QuizView controller="App.testController"}}
```

With

```
{{#view App.QuizView controllerBinding="App.testController"}}
```

You could try this solution [in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Uvqf/).

Comment: You could accept the answer if the solution is fine for you :)

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow says I have to wait a couple of minutes before I'm able to answer it. You're too fast for it!

Comment: Oh sorry, I was just trying to learn you something on SO! My apologizes