# How do I bind a controller to the view when the controller is create by Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

this question is slightly related to [How to display the “content” of an ObjectController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12816915/how-to-display-the-content-of-an-objectcontroller/12816978#12816978)
However, in the provided solution and all other examples I can find the controllers are always created explicitly. The nice thing about Ember.js is that the Route takes care of mostly everything. So I don't want to create the controller but want to bind it to a view:

```
{{view App.myview controllerBinding="App.applicationController"}}
```

You can see the complete example in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncaZz/1/). The example is not that great because Ember usually sets the controller of a child view to its parent view.

In the end I need to know, how I can access a controller which is created by Ember from a view.

Thanks for any help!

**Update:**
I provided the wrong fiddle or it did not save my changes. Here is the link to the right version: http://jsfiddle.net/ncaZz/1/

What should I provide in line 9 in the templates?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to bind to it.  You can access the controller from the view by calling it like this.

```
this.get('controller');
```

Updated Answer:

You really should not have your click event inside your view.  Your actions should either be in your controller or your router.

Your template should become

```
<span style="background-color: green" {{action doStuff}}>
    Click
</span>
```

and you should have a controller that should have this

```
App.MyController = Em.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['application'],
    doStuff: function(){
       this.get('controllers.application').foo();
    }
});
```

Also, the MyView and MyController should be capitalized, because when extending these items from ember that are not instances, and the capitalization is required.  The view should only really have stuff in the didInsertElement that handles special things like any kind of jquery animations or initializing a date picker.  But, the "ember way" is to have action in the router or controller.

Comment: It's not about that. I need to bind a different controller first.

Comment: I updated the answer for you to use the action from the controller.

Comment: Okay, should I ever try to bind an instance Ember.js created?

Comment: I don't think so.  By using needs: you get access to it, which is basically like binding.

Answer (score 0):

From the view you can access the controller with

```
this.controller
```

If you need other controllers than your view controller you can use the needs in the viewcontroller:

```
App.DatasetEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['mappingIndex']
});
```

and then use:

```
this.controller.mappingIndex
```

Comment: Well, the view does not have a controller. It does not one such as the TextAreaView. However, I don't know if Ember creates such a controller anyway.

Comment: @Karsten The view binds to the underlying controller by default. And you're right, it will create the controller anyways under the hood so you might as well create it yourself.